# How to use NOT IN sql query in django

Tags: sql, django

Im new to Django. Anyone help me to write "Not In" sql query in django.
here i used raw() query set without raw() query set how to write this query in django.

```
query = 'SELECT basic_uom FROM uom_master WHERE id="'+ id +'" and basic_uom not in (SELECT next_uom from uom_master WHERE id="'+ id +'") and basic_uom not in(SELECT std_uom FROM std_uom_master WHERE id"'+ id +'")ORDER BY next_uom ASC'
data = uom_master.objects.raw(query)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting..?

Comment: Its showing have error in sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[1,2,3]` is your list then you can do something like this, you modify according to your table names

```
uom_master.objects.filter(id=some_id).exclude(id__in=[1,2,3]).order_by("next_uom")
```

To get list of ids you can do like

```
list_of_ids = std_uom_master.objects.filter().values_list("id",flat=True)
```

filter is your filtering criteria and exclude is records to be omitted.

See [filters like id__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) and [guide about making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: You don't need to call `filter()` here

Comment: Yes you are right but OP has where clause and NOT IN here `WHERE id="'+ id +'") and basic_uom not in` @JPG

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari Thanks now i got it.